# Display flex issue, doesn't work but it does in parent divs?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, display

I have a stupid problem that I don't understand.
I am trying to remake a website from the Internet (https://delivery.tikibistro.ro/meniu), but I got stuck on the menu. I make a `div` for every part of the `nav`, **square**, a **square (red)** and for the **h1** and **h1 (text)**. I used `position: fixed` for the main menu (main div), `display: fixed` because the menu needs to stay on the top of the screen when I scroll. Also I used `display: flex` to position the rest of the elements inside of the `nav`. It's working, it's ok but when I want to set the position of the **text (h1)** inside the **square (red)** doesn't work. I verified it with `element inspection` and it's good there, but I don't have display block as google says.

Thank you for support,

I know it might be a simple problem but I really don't know what to do.

***HTML:***

```
<!-- 3.04.2023 https://delivery.tikibistro.ro/ -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main-menu.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Main Menu START HERE -->
    <header>
        <nav class="menu">
            <div class="menu-left">
            
            </div>

            <!-- Search bar START HERE -->
            <div class="search-bar">

            </div>
            <!-- Search bar STOP HERE -->

            <div class="menu-right">
                <!-- Delivery button -->
                <div class="delivery-square"><h1 id="delivery-t">Comanda acum</h1></div>
                
                <!-- Contact the staff directly from website via email/phone/social media,etc -->
                <h1 id="contact-t">Contact</h1>
            </div>



        </nav>


    </header>


    <!-- Main Menu STOP HERE -->



    <!-- Food menu START HERE -->
    <section>
        <nav class="food-menu">
            <li>Best Sellers</li>
            <li>Mexican</li>
        </nav>
    </section>
    <!-- Food menu STOP HERE -->


</body>
</html>l
```

***CSS (menu):***

```
 .menu{
    /* if position is fixed,the menu will always be on the screen */
    
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #131315;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 98;
} 
.menu-right{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: black;

}

.delivery-square{
    width: 156px;
    height: 48px;
    background: #f53b34;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0,.1607843137254902);
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-right: 28px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;
    display:inherit;
    justify-content: inherit;
}

#delivery-t{
    display: inherit;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-right: 28px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700px;
    color: #fff;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    display:inherit;
    justify-content: inherit;
}

#contact-t {
    position:inherit;
    right: 0px;
    color: red;
}

.food-menu{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -650px;
    
}
```

***CSS (body):***

```
body, html {
    font-family: SF Pro Text;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #131315;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    /* position: relative; */
}
```

[This is what the element inspection shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXABq.png)

As I say, `display: flex` works but when I use it for **text (h1)** it doesn't work anymore. I tried to combine the **square** and the **h1** in a single `div` but it doesn't work.